# JFrame with four sliders

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am writing a control panel with Sliders but I think my code is messy and cumbersome, what can I do to improve it?

```
public class Input_Window extends JFrame {
    JSlider myslideA,myslideB,myslideC,myslideD;

    Input_Window(){
        System.out.println("* Control Window");
        setBackground(Color.GRAY);  
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Controls");
        setSize(200,400);
        setLocation(1200,250);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        myslideA=slider(0,10,3,1,true,true);
        add(myslideA);
        myslideB=slider(0,10,3,1,true,true);
        add(myslideB);
        myslideC=slider(0,10,3,1,true,true);
        add(myslideC);
        myslideD=slider(0,10,3,1,true,true);
        add(myslideD);
        setVisible(true);  
        setFocusable(true); 
        requestFocus();
    }

    public final JSlider slider(int min, int max, int def, int maj, boolean ticks, boolean labels){

        JSlider myslide=new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,min,max,def);
        myslide.setMajorTickSpacing(maj);
        myslide.setPaintTicks(ticks);
        myslide.setPaintLabels(labels);
        return (myslide);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. **Naming:**
   Your class is named `Input_Window` which violates standard Java naming conventions of `PascalCase` (without underscores).
2. **Formatting:**
   An equal sign should be surrounded by spaces:

   ```
   myslideA = slider(0,10,3,1,true,true);
   //and so on...
   ```
3. **Visibilities:**

   - Your JSliders should most probably be `private`. nobody aside from
     your InputWindow should have to know about them. If there's someone out there who wants to know about GUI **except the GUI** you're doing things wrong ...
   - `slider` should also be private. If somebody else uses it, extract it to a utility-class. Hide the information where ever you can. If you don't things may happen with your stuff when you're not watching.
4. **Responsibilities:**
   Your constructor shouldn't request focus and set the window to visible himself. That's things that should be done in calling code. You don't expect a `JFrame` to show up on instantiation either, right?

Comment: Agreed on #4. If it were normal for `JFrame`s to make themselves visible and request focus, then the `JFrame` constructor would have done so.